# What is the difference between the ranges "^4" and "^4.."?

Tags: c#, range

I was trying to get the substring from a string I am using in my program as follows:

```
mystring.Substring(mystring.Length - 4)
```

The Visual Studio IntelliSense recommended I use index and range operators as follows:

```
mystring[^4..]
```

I glanced through the documentation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/proposals/csharp-8.0/ranges) and it seems like using just `mystring[^4]` would work just fine. Why does the IntelliSense recommend to use the extra `..` in there, are there any benefits from adding it?

Comment: ^4 is one character, ^4.. is a string

Comment: It's well explained. You might want to do more than *glance through* the docs. :)

Comment: try writing a little test program with both

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`^4` is an *index*, representing a *single index number* which just so happens to be 4 away from the end of the array. This is essentially the same as doing `mystring[0]`, just dynamically figuring out the number based on the length.

`^4..` is a *range*, which means *everything between* (and including) the 4th-to-last index and the end of the array.

```
var input = "abcdefghijk";
Console.WriteLine(input[^4]);
Console.WriteLine(input[^4..]);
```

This prints

```
h
hijk
```

Answer (score 2):

The `..` operator is used to specify a range, while the values on either side are used to indicate indexes.

Using a single index will give a single value, using the `..` operator will give a slice of multiple values:

```cs
public static void Main()
    {
        var array = new int[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };

        Console.WriteLine(array[^3].GetType());
        // Equivalent to 
        // array[new Index(3, fromEnd: true)]

        Console.WriteLine(array[^3..].GetType());
        // Equivalent to 
        // array[Range.EndAt(new Index(3, fromEnd: true))]
    }
```

Outputs

```
System.Int32 // notice the lack of []
System.Int32[]
```